# Disable access to wp-admin except for profile.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to restrict access to any/all of the `/wp-admin/` pages for a specific user role (in this case 'subscribers') except for their profile page.

My current implementation:

```
function redirected_admin(){

  if ( ! defined('DOING_AJAX') && ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && $GLOBALS['pagenow'] !== 'profile.php' ) {

      $url = get_edit_user_link();

      wp_redirect( $url );
      exit;      
  }

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirected_admin' );
```

This currently leaves the "Dashboard" option visible that just redirects to the profile page.

Is there a better/similar way to achieve this sort of functionality that hides any of the sidebar entries completely?

Comment: If you are willing to use some ugly JavaScript this can be done in a few lines. A pure PHP solution is also possible but would it would also be ugly. I do not believe there is a clean solution as there does not appear to be any filter/action to prevent .../wp-admin/menu-header.php from generating output. The only possibility I see is to clean the output after it is generated.

Comment: Just a matter of cleaning the output with either Javascript or PHP then I think. Probably best to keep it within the PHP under the same hook. Thanks for the pointers @magenta.